# MQTT as a broker for celery

Tags: python, celery, mqtt

I want to implement Celery with MQTT as a broker instead of rabbittMQ.The official celery document doesn't provide any way for doing this.
Is there any way so that I can achieve it.

Comment: You understand that MQTT is a protocol, not a broker implementation? RabbitMQ has a plugin to support MQTT, but it is a pub/sub protocol, not a queuing system so may not actually be capable of doing what your asking as every subscriber gets every message on a given topic

Comment: can I make a new one using MQTT broker